# Flutter How to fix exception caught by svg

Tags: flutter

How can I fix this SVG error ?

[image]

Also this is my Svg widget:

```
  SvgPicture.asset(truckSVG,
                            
                                width: 80,
                                height: 80,
                                color: ColorConstants.birincilRenk,
                                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `flutter_svg` don't support all svg feauters. Your svg file contains `<style>` tag that is unsupported by the library.

To solve it, you can use [svgcleaner](https://github.com/RazrFalcon/svgcleaner) or any other tool to clean unnecessary data from svg image.

Comment: I figured out myself. At the begining, I edited these svg files with CorelDraw. It is the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The error log clearly states, it doesn't accept "print" units like **mm** (most certainly the same for inch etc.).

To achieve a DIN A4 aspect ratio, you could fix your width and height values by using pixels or percentages:

```
width: 210px;
height: 297px;

width: 70.707%;
height: 100%;

width: 100%;
height: 141.4286%;
```

Comment: I figured out myself. At the begining, I edited these svg files with CorelDraw. It is the problem. Thank you.